# Correcting some values during import

Tags: error, import, data-import

I imported certain contact records. Somehow Civicrm filled the country field with country data of its choice for certain records. Now I would like to edit those records. I have exported the records along with contact ID, edited the country field. But while importing there should be a contact ID field for matching to contact. It is not available. So how should I fix this error? how I go about?

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: 4.7.22 is the version